# How to create two buttons with images and url link information retrieved from database table

Tags: android

Originally in the project I have two image buttons, which I coded like the below:
XML:

```
<ImageView
          android:layout_width="125dp"
          android:layout_height="125dp"
          android:id="@+id/sidebanner1"
          android:padding="15dp" 
    />


<ImageView
          android:layout_width="125dp"
          android:layout_height="125dp"
          android:id="@+id/sidebanner2"
          android:padding="15dp" 
/>
```

Main_Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{ 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ImageView SideBanner1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sidebanner1);
        SideBanner1.setImageResource(R.drawable.sidebanner1);
        SideBanner1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String url1 = "http://www.chris.com";

                Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                a.setData(Uri.parse(url1));
                startActivity(a);
    }
});

        ImageView SideBanner2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sidebanner2);
        SideBanner2.setImageResource(R.drawable.sidebanner2);
        SideBanner2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String url2 = "http://www.peter.com";

                Intent b = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                b.setData(Uri.parse(url2));
                startActivity(b);
    }
});
```

Now I have stored the images and url links in server, and created sql table in order to retrieve these information.
In the splash screen, I started to retrieve the information as follow:

```
JSONArray sidebannerAry = result.getJSONArray("sidebannerData");
                for (int i = 0; i < sidebannerAry.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject temp = sidebannerAry.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    String image = DefensiveClass.optString(temp, "bannerImage");
                    String url = DefensiveClass.optString(temp, "bannerURL");

                    map.put("image", image);
                    map.put("url", url);

                    MainActivity.sidebannerAry.add(map);
                }
```

But now I got confused and not sure how to apply the data to the two buttons in MainActivity.
Can anyone guide me thru how to pass the image and link information retrieved to the two banner buttons so that they can use it. Thank you.

In MainActivity public class, I added:

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> sidebannerAry = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

Problem solved, I was thinking assigning sidebannerAry to adapter to do it.
But I was stupid, all I need is just to load the image  and have the onClickListener open up the website and load the url directly from the sidebannerAry.

Comment: question is not clear ??

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you need to set your buttons with the information retrieved from api call, so you can simply store the values retrieved from api call(server) on local variables and apply those to the buttons as:

```
btnExample.setText(the_text_or_url_retrieved_from_server);
```

and if you want to set image to the button with the image url retrieved from server then you can use glide as:

```
  Glide.with(context)
.load(url_retrieved_from_server)
.into(imageButton);
```

but make sure you use image button for this.

Comment: Do I need to use adapter to set up for the array list?